# How to insert html in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, inject

Hallo all: I need to insert a html string in a iframe as shown below:

....

```
var html = "<html><head><title>Titolo</title></head><body><p>body</p></body></html>"

jQuery('#popolaIframe').click(function() {
  parent.$("#indexIframe")[0].documentElement.innerHTML = html;     
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: As a possible alternative (without knowing what you want to achieve): consider using a div with `overflow:auto;` to get the 'iframe' effect (= bounded area with dedicated scrollbar).

Comment: The div is not an alternative since I receive an html with head tag.
Populate divs with a so formed html cause the browser to drop all the head content.

Comment: Yeah, I see your problem. You *may* have to pursue that avenue of thought, though, as far as I know this is the sort of thing that the same-origin policy of JavaScript covers - so you may have to extract the `<body>` part and any header data you need to preserve (e.g. stylesheets). Either way, good luck. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var html = "<html><head><title>Titolo</title></head><body><p>body</p></body></html>"

jQuery('#popolaIframe').click(function() {
  var doc = parent.$("#indexIframe")[0].documentElement;
  doc.open();
  doc.write(html);
  doc.close();     
});
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out this solution, here is something similar which worked for me:
mydoc = document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.document; mydoc.write(html_code); mydoc.close();

Comment: I don't think `document.close` is needed here as `document.write` will do so itself. the `.close` happens implicitly too.

Answer (score 1):

Does that code you posted work? If not, it's probably because browsers disallow modification of iframe content for security reasons.

Comment: The code does not work.
This below work.
parent.$("#indexIframe")[0].contentDocument.body.innerHTML = "foo";

The problem is that since I receive a well formed html with head content I cannot put it in the contentDocument.body.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can get a refrence to the body so I don't see why not:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_contentdocument

Comment: No i cannot reference the body: since I have to inject a correct html with head and body:
The real html is this:
var html = '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css"/></head><body><p>body</p></body></html>';

And if I insert the html in the document.body.innerHTML all the head content is dropped.

Kind regards

Comment: although undesired in the body under normal circumstances... does it work if you put the `link` tag in the body?

Comment: It works with browsers since the browsers do not cut the definition.
I receive a problem with the jQuery api clone() with ie6 and the problem is caused by the link tag in the body.
Still seeking.... :)

Answer (score 0):

You have lost 1 level, you need modify innerHtml of body, but not document:

```
document.body.innerHTML = bla-bla
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert into an iframe unless you `remove()` the iframe and use 'append(html)'. You can insert it inside iframes body like

```
$('body',parent.$("#indexIframe")[0].contentWindow.document).html(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternitevely if not sure about the parent element you could do that:

```
var doc = $.find("#myIframe")[0].contentWindow.document; //that will look in the whole dom though
doc.open();
doc.write(html);
```

At least this did the job in my case :)